# C++ Array prints zeros before numbers and doesn't print 9

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a tic tac toe board but I'm having two problems. (Sorry if the format of this question is bad, this is my first time asking a question here)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
```

One problem (the array declaration below) is that when the program runs (as shown at the very bottom), the last number (9) doesn't print it's just blank. If I replace the 9 with another number (for example, 5) it prints it out just like the other numbers. I can't figure out why it wont print for the number 9

```
char board[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

int row;
int column;

void display_board();

int main()
{
   display_board();

   return 0;
}

void display_board()
{
   for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
   {
      for (column = 0; column < 3; column++)
      {
         cout << board[row][column];
      }
      cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

The other problem is that when the program runs (as shown below), it prints three zeros before every number. I just want the 1-9 not the three zeros. I can't figure out why those three zeros are even there, let alone getting rid of them. Any and all help is appreciated thank you.

[image: Program Run]

Comment: I am fairly certain that nothing gets printed correctly here. Very few terminals will provide a reasonable visual representation of ASCII control characters.

Comment: Why are you entering integers into a char array? You should be entering them as chars like this: `{{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};` Or as songyuanyao has said, use an int array instead. I'm not sure if this will solve your problem though.

Comment: The control character at 0x09 is the backspace, which is why you're not seeing it output.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
char board[3][3] = {{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};
```

have fun coding, and try read some books on the way

Comment: Incorrect, Chars should be entered with single quotes (e.g. '1') not with double quotation marks (e.g "1") in C++. Only use double quotation marks for Strings.

Comment: @MrPigeon yeah, I noticed, thx for reminding me, old habit dies hard

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help everyone.

It's true, the problem could be fixed by either putting the numbers in the array declaration in single quotes or by changing the array itself to an int. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`char board[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};`

to

`int board[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};`

(Make your char array an integer array).

There is nothing else that seems to be wrong in your program. I just quickly ran it in an IDE and I am getting the desired output after changing the array to int.